# Paypal MVC3 integration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, paypal

**Scenario**
MVC application with custom shopping cart. Shopping cart integrates with a PayPal, passing sale data like client information, product items and prices (for each item and total price) but not credit card or paypal information. This would be set on paypal.

**Problem**
Paypal describes how to use the cart upload to integrate with custom shopping carts here:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_cart_upload#id09BLDK0007Q
But there is very little detail on how to do it.

After a while i found an example of how to do the MVC-Paypal interaction (even though is not cart upload but it is a mater of configuration) here:
http://www.arunrana.net/2012/01/paypal-integration-in-mvc3-and-razor.html

The problem in this solution is that it appears to have some security problems. Sensitive data is set to a view and sent to the client in hidden fields and post is set by javascript, making this unacceptable right? Or am i seeing this wrong?

**Intended Solution**

1. User sees shopping car and clicks checkout button, causing a post to *myserver.com/Controller/Action* passing client data like name, address, etc.
2. The controller action *myserver.com/Controller/Action* builds a post server side, adding the client post data information more sensitive information like prices and paypal merchant specific information and posts request to paypal OR invoques paypal webservice.
3. Paypal returns a token, or some other information and *myserver.com/Controller/Action* redirects client to Paypal to make the payment.

**Question**
Is my intended solution possible? How can i, in response of a post from the client, make some processing in the controller, post/invoke Paypal with the result of that processing and ultimately pass paypals response to the client for him to interact directly with Paypal?
Otherwise i can't see how it could be "secure".

If not, surely someone have done something similar and can point me into the right direction :-)

Answer (score 0):

I sort of understand what your trying to do here, and I think I can answer that question. Let me know if this doesnt quite make sense...

So your customer hits your resource, mysite.com/Cart/Checkout. The controller instantiates the model and then passes the object into the view, where the view binds values appropriately.

Customer clicks 'Pay with PayPal' and is redirected to mysite.com/Cart/ExpressCheckout. The controller instantiates the model, and the model will handle the SetExpressCheckout call utilizing the cart session data (item, amounts, etc), then the model (or controller, this part is a bit vague) would redirect the customer to pp.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-12345566788

The customer would fill everything out and once done, they would be redirected to mtsite.com/Cart/ConfirmOrder. In this resource, the Model would handle the GetExpressCheckoutDetails call, setting properties for all the data returned, etc. The controller would pass the object into the view and the view would bind appropriately.

Is there a reason why this is insecure? This should be secure and follow all standards of Microsoft MVC3. Except the part where you do the redirect, semantically, I'm unsure whether this would be done in the controller or the model. I think it would be the controller though.